# DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory vs DefaultMessageListenerContainer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jms

What are the advantages of using `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` over `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` ?

- If i configure DMLC directly , i do get a handle to check the status by calling `isRunning()`. Also i do get a facility to start and stop the DMLC
- However, per new spring specs, if i configure `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` , i do not get handle of DMLC, so i am unable to do any of above operations.

So looking at above limitation, can somebody explain why one should use `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` over DMLC

Also, if i use `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` , what are the ways to achive above functionality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The factory was introduced to support the creation of listener containers for `@JmsListener` annotated POJO methods.

If you are not using that mechanism, you can continue to define your DLMC directly.

**EDIT**

When using `@JmsListener`, the containers are not registered as beans themselves, but are available using the registry bean; you can get a reference to the container so you can start/stop etc.

See the [javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/jms/config/JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.html) for the  `JmsListenerEndpointRegistry` for how to get references to the containers either individually by id, or all.

**EDIT2**

I am not sure what you mean in comment 3; the registry has all containers, regardless of which container factory was used to create the container...

```
@JmsListener(id="foo", destination="foo", containerFactory="one")
public void listen1(String payload) {
    System.out.println(payload + "foo");
}

@JmsListener(id="bar", destination="bar", containerFactory="two")
public void listen2(String payload) {
    System.out.println(payload + "bar");
}
```

If you are using `configureListenerContainers()` to programmatically create endpoints, you have to provide them with containers not container factories.

Comment: I am using @JmsListener ...However in that case also there should be some handle to start and stop the listener manually

Comment: I tried above approach and it worked. However, in my application i am going to create two instances of DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory as i have two diff QM. In that case, how can i add two factories from configureJmsListeners method?

Comment: See my next edit. It's generally better to ask a new question rather than commenting on a closed one.