# Configuring multiple DefaultJmslistenercontainerfactory

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms

In my app, I have 2 diff mq conn factory beans. For this I have 2 diff DefaultJmslistenercontainerfactory beans ex cf1 n cf2. Each of DefaultJmslistenercontainerfactory bean is being referred in seperate @JmsListener. ..Now i want to start  stop each listrner programatically , for that I am overriding configureMessageListeners(JmsListenerRegistrar) method where I can set the DefaultJmslistenercontainerfactory instance. Note I only one instance can be set..
then in my code I get spring instance of JmsListenerRegistry from which I can get list dmlc..which I can start n stop
However. .since I have set only one DefaultJmslistenercontainerfactory instance, my code returns only one dmlc..
Question here is how can I pass multiple DefaultJmslistenercontainerfactory instances in configureJmsListener() method?? 
Note- I do not create dmlc manually..I just configure factory..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why are you using `configureMessageListeners()` ? That is for programmatic endpoint registration, not influencing the configuration of `@JmsListener`.

Show your configuration **(edit the question, don't try to post code/config in comments)**.

This works fine for me...

```
@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<DefaultMessageListenerContainer> one(
        @Qualifier("jmsConnectionFactory1") ConnectionFactory cf) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(cf);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<DefaultMessageListenerContainer> two(
        @Qualifier("jmsConnectionFactory2") ConnectionFactory cf) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(cf);
    return factory;
}

@JmsListener(id="fooListener", destination="foo", containerFactory="one")
public void listen1(String payload) {
    System.out.println(payload + "foo");
}

@JmsListener(id="barListener", destination="bar", containerFactory="two")
public void listen2(String payload) {
    System.out.println(payload + "bar");
}
```

...

```
@Autowired
JmsListenerEndpointRegistry registry;
```

...

```
MessageListenerContainer fooContainer = registry.getListenerContainer("fooListener");
MessageListenerContainer barContainer = registry.getListenerContainer("barListener");
```

You can also use `registry.getListenerContainers()` to get a collection.

I thought I explained all this in [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33406925/defaultjmslistenercontainerfactory-vs-defaultmessagelistenercontainer/33414914#33414914).

Comment: Yep, got your answer. I thought it will create multiple Registries for different DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory instances. Is there any way i can get the id's of the Listeners dynamically? I want to display on the screen the id of the listener and its running status. MessageListenerContainer doesn't provide that api

Comment: There's not currently an API to get the list of listener container ids.

I have opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13633) which you can track.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475344/displaying-the-listeners-and-their-status-in-my-application/33479606#33479606) the functionality should be available shortly.