# Displaying the listeners and their status in my application

Tags: spring, spring-jms

In my spring application, i want to display the Listeners and their running status.I am using @JmsListener anotation. 
I got hint from this url - [Configuring multiple DefaultJmslistenercontainerfactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458184/configuring-multiple-defaultjmslistenercontainerfactory/33463162#33463162)

However, i am also facing a same challenge, I do get the listener statuses but not getting Id's of the listener. Further on, i want to start/stop the listener using same ids

How can i get the id's of the Listeners?

Answer (score 1):

There's not currently an API to get the list of listener container ids.

I have opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13633) which you can track.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. That's now implemented and will be available in `4.2.3.RELEASE` due around next week.